# How to perform a function for every day on spreadsheet data of an entire year

Tags: python, excel, time, series, spss

[image: Data here]

I have Fitbit data for an entire year. I am calculating heart rate(HR) variability from the changes in HR over time. The function to calculate it is using root mean square RMSSD = sqrt(average(X:Xn)).

I have already calculated the X value I need for the equation, but I want it to automatically detect the date, run the equation from all the values from that date, then go to the next date on the list and same value. So, this will theoretically break down all the data from a year into 365 cells.

I've attached an image of my Excel file. Basically, I want to be able to run the function above on the RRS column for all the data within one day and return one value per day.

Comment: How is the value for one day calculated? Average? You could use a pivot table to show each day with just one value.

Comment: This is just a snapshot of 10/30/18. There are around 10000 cells for the entire day. Then the next day has roughly the same number of cells. I'm going to average all the values under column RRS for one day then take sqrt of that number.

Comment: you added an SPSS tag - do you have the data available in SPSS? if so you can get what you need by running this in a new syntax window: `aggregate out=* /break=date /MNRRS=mean(RRS).`

Comment: With 10,000 entries per day, you will not be able to fit a full year into a single column.  So if you need daily averages for a year, you might want to first think about how you are planning to organize your data.

Comment: Thanks Eli-K that seemed to work. Do you know if you can execute similar function that would let you perform calculation for an entire month?

Answer (score 0):

Ahmed, you can perform that same mean calculation using AGGREGATE on any subsets of  data in SPSS Statistics that you can designate with one or a combination of multiple variables. If you have a month variable, you simply break on that month variable if you want to combine all values over the month rather than the day.

In response to the request for an example, in the example data files that come with SPSS Statistics, open the file worldsales.sav. There are three variables in the file, Continent, Product, and Revenue. If you wanted to average (or sum, or take a variety other summary functions) Revenue for each Product you would specify Data>Aggregate, move the Product variable to the Break Variable(s) box, move Revenue into the Summaries of Variables box, and if desired, edit the function to change it from MEAN to something else, and perhaps change the name and/or label for the new variable. The new variable can be added back to the dataset (the default) or output to a new dataset or file, using the additional options in the Save section of the dialog box.

If you wanted to aggregate values by Continent, you could use that variable as a break variable instead of Product. If you wanted to get a distinct value for each Product on each Continent, you could include both those variables as break variables, and you'd get this.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example to illustrate how to do what you're suggesting?